# Funcionamiento de removeViewAt y addView

Tags: android, android-studio

estoy intentando sustituir un boton/objeto, lo tengo dentro de un LinearLayout. Entonces uso esos metodos para eliminar el que esta y añadir en la posicion que estaba el otro el nuevo, pero hace lo que quiere o cambia en los finales (es un 3x3 de botones en el LinearLayout), ¿alguien me podría ayudar?

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   hasClick(((TileView) view).x, ((TileView) view).y,((TileView) view).topElements,((TileView) view).index, l2, ((TileView) view).getId());
                }
            });


protected void hasClick(int x, int y,int elements,int index, LinearLayout l2, int eliminar)
{
    TileView tv = new TileView(this,x,y,elements,index,pictures[index]);
    index = tv.getNewIndex();

    TextView tvNumberOfClicks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clicksTxt);
    contador++;
    for (int i = 0; i < topTileY; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < topTileX; j++) {
            if(j == x && i == y)
            {
                tv = new TileView(this,x,y,elements,index,pictures[index]);
                tv.setHeight(height);
                tv.setWidth(width);
                l2.removeViewAt(eliminar);
                l2.addView(tv,eliminar);
            }

        }
    }
    //compruebo que obtengo la posicion del los objetos en el Linear
    tvNumberOfClicks.setText(String.valueOf(eliminar));
}
```

TileView

```
package com.example.killtrols.casillas;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.R.attr.button;

/**
 * Created by killtrols on 15/11/2017.
 */

public class TileView extends AppCompatButton {
    // coordenadas
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;
    // trama a mostrar
    public int index = 0;
    //max tramas
    public int topElements = 0;
    public TileView(Context context, int x, int y, int topElements, int index, int
            background) {
        super(context);
        this.x = x; //coordenada X
        this.y = y; //coordenada Y
        this.topElements = topElements; //max tramas
        this.index = index; //índice de trama
        this.setBackgroundResource(background);
    }
    public void setBackground(int id)
    {
        setBackgroundResource(id);
    }
    public int getNewIndex(){
        index ++;
        //controlar si necesitamos volver a comenzar el ciclo de tramas
        if (index == topElements)index = 0;
        return index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pon la clase TileView

Comment: Ya he puesto la clase TileView

Answer (score 0):

Cuando estas agregando tu tileview, tienes que ponerle el layout params.

```
tv = new TileView(this,x,y,elements,index,pictures[index]);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```